# Accessing Excel object model from another thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, excel, interop

I'm writing a library in VB.NET that would help with generating Excel reports.
I'm new to .NET/VS2010, so sorry if I'm trying to do something wrong.
One feature I need is a routine that would start a thread to do some work (refresh a workbook from an Access data source), while the main thread checks if any dialogs pop up in the Excel window as a result of the refresh failing.

The problem I am having is that the new thread is unable to reference the Excel.Application object. It doesn't produce an error, it just freezes.

Here is a demo of my situation:

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class xlTest
    Public xlApp As Excel.Application

    Sub DoBackgroundStuff()
        MsgBox ("DoBackgroundStuff() says: " & xlApp.Version)
    End Sub

    Sub New()
        xlApp = New Excel.Application
        MsgBox ("New() says: " & xlApp.Version)

        Dim t As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf DoBackgroundStuff)
        t.Start()
        Do While t.IsAlive
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep (100)
        Loop

        xlApp.Quit()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The DoBackgroundStuff procedure freezes when trying to reference any part of XlApp, without throwing an exception. If I add a breakpoint inside DoBackgroundStuff and try to watch XlApp, all its properties turn out to be "Unable to evaluate expression".
- Any other members of the class can be read by the thread just fine.
- I have tried a workaround by getting the Excel.Application object from the Process ID (which works just fine), but since this method uses MainWindowHandle it fails if the Excel window is not visible, which makes the workaround unusable for me.
Please point me to what I am doing wrong.
Many thanks!

Comment: do you need to add in xlApp.visible = true somewhere?

Comment: In order for the workaround I mentioned to work, yes. Then the thread can acquire the Application object from Excel's window. But I don't want Excel to be visible, and I'm sure it's not the only option. I'm pretty sure I have some basic stuff wrong, I just can't find what it is :-(

Comment: OK, I have found a solution... or so it seems. Creating the instance of xlApp in another thread has somehow _magically_ made it accessible to the main thread and any other threads. If someone could explain this magic to me, I will be eternally grateful.